# Should an object interact with the a main Activity?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm learning about Android, and I'm trying to apply Object Oriented Programming to an example app, but I have doubts about the structure of the app.

Let's say I want to make an app with three buttons, and another one that's capable to add more buttons. This buttons are a new class called *Button* .
So, the question is, it is recommended to this new class to have an instance of the Main Activity to interact with, or should everything that interact with the Main Activity be in the, Main Activity class?.

Comment: few sample code snippets will help us to answer your question.

Comment: No need to pass MainActivity instance, you can have one Parent Activity(say MainActivity) and it can have two fragments like MainFragment and SettingFragment, from setting fragment you can manage the state of the number of buttons to be shown in MainFragment.